# How to enable responsive design for Fabric.js

Tags: responsive-design, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is there a way to make a Fabric.js canvas resize with the browser to enable the same result on any device? I'm talking about responsive design.

Has anyone a code example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically you need to get the device screen's width and height. Afterwards just resize the canvas accordingly in your Javascript. Example:

```
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
var height = (window.innerHeight > 0) ? window.innerHeight : screen.height;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;
```

You might have screens with varying resolution ratios though, what I usually do in this case is calculate your original width's and the device's width ratio and then adjust both width and height accordingly with that value. Example:

```
var originalWidth = 960;  //Example value
var width = (window.innerWidth > 0) ? window.innerWidth : screen.width;
var widthRatio = originalWidth / width;
canvas.width *= widthRatio;
canvas.height *= widthRatio;
```

This usually works fine for me on any device, hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer sounds reasonable. Unfortunately it doesn't work in my example. Please view my jsfiddles with your code and without your code.
with:    http://jsfiddle.net/J9mUh/1/
without: http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/Nyf5Y/2/
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From what I read about FabricJS, you need to set canvas width and height through methods setWidth and setHeight. Try that and let me know if it works.

Comment: thank you. it works now. the canvas resizes. see http://jsfiddle.net/gcollect/Hx75y/2/

Anyway, my basic problem is, that I need the whole content of the canvas to behave responsive. All objects need to rerender based on to the new window settings. Any ideas? I give you a +1 for your solution anyway

Comment: You can set your canvas's onBeforeScaleRotate to do something with its contents.  But Joao answered the question you actually asked... you should give the check for it and ask a new question if you want to know something else...

Comment: would there ever be a case you don't have access to window object?

Comment: @AkinHwan The window object is the global object in the browser. Any global variables or functions can be accessed as properties of the window object. A global object is an object that always exists in the global scope. NodeJS, since it is not executed in a browser, would not have a window object. While in browsers the global scope is the window object, in nodeJS the global scope of a module is the module itself.

Answer (score 23):

This [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robsch/g8x9mjvt/) is a working solution. It is inspired by this github [issue](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/issues/3959).

These are the required things:

A div that surrounds the canvas that is controlled by fabric.

```
<div class="fabric-canvas-wrapper">
    <canvas id="theCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

And a window resize handler that triggers the calculation and setting of the new canvas dimension and the zoom.

```
window.onresize = resizeCanvas() {
    const outerCanvasContainer = document.getElementById('fabric-canvas-wrapper');

    const ratio          = canvas.getWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
    const containerWidth = outerCanvasContainer.clientWidth;
    const scale          = containerWidth / canvas.getWidth();
    const zoom           = canvas.getZoom() * scale;

    canvas.setDimensions({width: containerWidth, height: containerWidth / ratio});
    canvas.setViewportTransform([zoom, 0, 0, zoom, 0, 0]);
}
```

That's all. It seems to work perfectly. Please let me know if any issues come up with this solution.

I have used fabric.js in version 3.6.2.

Comment: Thanks for this snippet. Just, I think you don't need to declare `containerHeight` (never used)

Comment: This works for me, but after any click event. Any solutions @robsch?

Comment: @SarathMohandas What is your problem? Does the fiddle work for you or not?

Comment: @robsch This works for me in angular, but after click events the layout appears.

Comment: @SarathMohandas I'm afraid I cannot help you with this. You could create a new question, if you don't find a solution for you problem.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's been a while but i found an easier way to do it using the zoom feature.

This code is triggered when the window resize is completed. It allows me to determine based on the new dimension, the zoom factor needed to resize everything in the canvas.

```js
function rescale_canvas_if_needed()
{
 var optimal_dimensions = get_optimal_canvas_dimensions();
 var scaleFactor=optimal_dimensions[0]/wpd.canvas_w;
 if(scaleFactor != 1) {
  wpd_editor.canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0]);
  wpd_editor.canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1]);
  wpd_editor.canvas.setZoom(scaleFactor);
  wpd_editor.canvas.calcOffset();
  wpd_editor.canvas.renderAll();
  }
}

$( window ).resize(function() {
 clearTimeout(resizeId);
 resizeId = setTimeout(handle_resize, 500);
 });
 
 function handle_resize()
 {
 $(".canvas-container").hide();
 rescale_canvas_if_needed();
 $(".canvas-container").show();               
  
 }
```

Comment: This looks like it will be sooo good... but what does `get_optimal_canvas_dimensions` do? Also the code snippets not working  :(

Comment: Hello,Sorry for the late answer, I just got the notification. That function is one of mines which checks the available space in the area where the canvas is shown and resize the canvas itself accordingly.

Comment: [code]function get_optimal_canvas_dimensions()
        {
            var available_width = $("#wpc-editor-container").outerWidth();
            var canvas_w = 0;
            var canvas_h = 0;
            if (wpd.canvas_w > available_width)
            {
                canvas_w = available_width;
                canvas_h = (canvas_w * wpd.canvas_h) / wpd.canvas_w;
            }
            else
            {
                canvas_w = wpd.canvas_w;
                canvas_h = wpd.canvas_h;
            }

            return [canvas_w, canvas_h];
        }[code]

Comment: Thank you! I hashed my own implementation of that function in the end but thanks for the update :)

Comment: Worked for me for canvas on mobile. Also please note that you'll need to set zoom to 1 before save canvas to dataURI. In this case you'll have full image instead of zoomed copy.

Comment: Please provide full code. get_optimal_canvas_dimensions is having undefined variables.

Comment: I reworked this into a working example in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63511300/1815624

Answer (score 2):

i thought this one was the answer I needed https://stackoverflow.com/a/29445765/1815624

it seemed so close but after some adjustments I got what I wanted it down scales when needed and maxes out at a scale of 1.

The canvas size you desire should be set as width/height `var optimal_dimensions = [1000,1000];`

this needs some more changes to handle height as well so when a user rotates there phone to landscape it may become to big to see it all on the screen
the new edited code will be at 1000 pixels in width and height for this demo

update: added detection for height and width to scale to window...

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>

    

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/4.0.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
   <script>
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({ radius: 30, fill: '#f55', top: 100, left: 100 }));

  canvas.item(0).set({
    borderColor: 'gray',
    cornerColor: 'black',
    cornerSize: 12,
    transparentCorners: true
  });
  canvas.setActiveObject(canvas.item(0));
  canvas.renderAll();

 
function rescale_canvas_if_needed(){
    var optimal_dimensions = [400,400];
    var scaleFactorX=window.innerWidth/optimal_dimensions[0];
    var scaleFactorY=window.innerHeight/optimal_dimensions[1];
    if(scaleFactorX <  scaleFactorY && scaleFactorX < 1) {
        canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0] *scaleFactorX);
        canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1] *scaleFactorX);
        canvas.setZoom(scaleFactorX);
    } else if(scaleFactorX >  scaleFactorY && scaleFactorY < 1){
        canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0] *scaleFactorY);
        canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1] *scaleFactorY);
        canvas.setZoom(scaleFactorY);
    }else {
        canvas.setWidth(optimal_dimensions[0] );
        canvas.setHeight(optimal_dimensions[1] );
        canvas.setZoom(1);
    }

    canvas.calcOffset();
    canvas.renderAll();
}

 
function handle_resize(){
    $(".canvas-container").hide();
    rescale_canvas_if_needed();
    $(".canvas-container").show();               
     
}
var resizeId = null;
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if(resizeId != null)
        clearTimeout(resizeId);
        resizeId = setTimeout(handle_resize, 500);
     });
    console.log( "ready!" );
    /* auto size it right away... */
    resizeId = setTimeout(handle_resize, 500);
});
    </script>
```

hope this helps someone...good day.

Answer (score 0):

Resize the canvas depending on the size of an element with jQuery.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.setHeight(jQuery('#image').height());
    canvas.setWidth(jQuery('#image').width());
    canvas.renderAll();
}
resizeCanvas();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best solution for responsive canvas or you can define different size based on device.

```php
<?PHP
  $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    
  function isMobileDevice($user_agent) {
      return preg_match('/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i', $user_agent);
  }
    
  if (isMobileDevice($user_agent)) {
      echo '<canvas id="mobileCanvas" width="390" height="390"></canvas>';
  } else {
      echo '<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>';
  }
?>
```

And here is Js.

```js
let canvasElement;
if (window.innerWidth <= 500) {
  canvasElement = 'mobileCanvas';
} else {
  canvasElement = 'myCanvas';
}
  
const canvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvasElement);
```

Note: You can use the same id as well for both. But one canvas will load at a time, I have tested it and everything working great.