# FabricJS how to ensure annotation sticks to position on the page and NOT viewport (Might be a pure JS/CSS problem)

Tags: javascript, css, fabricjs

I'm wondering if it is possible to have the canvas span out the entire page instead of just the viewport. Here's a picture illustration of what I'm trying to achieve:

*So here we have a drawing on the text page1. This annotation is located at the top of the page.*
[image: So here we have a drawing on the text page1. This annotation is located at the top of the page.]

*As i scroll down, the annotation follows me*

[image: As i scroll down, the annotation follows me]

**However, what I want is for the annotation to stay at the exact location it was drawn at even when scrolling.**

*This unwanted behaviour is because of how I initialized the canvas:*

**index.js**

```
    const initCanvas = (id) => {
    return new fabric.Canvas(id,
        {
            width: window.innerWidth,
            height: window.innerHeight,
            zindex: 99,
            overlayColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85)',
        })
}
```

**index.css**

```
    .canvas-container {
    position: fixed !important;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<body>
  <div id="root">
   ....
  <canvas id="canvas">
  </canvas>
</div>
</body>
```

The question can also be rephrased as, is there a way to initialize the canvas to cover the entire screen instead of just the viewport?

If that's not possible, is there a smart workaround I can do to achieve the behavior I want?

**Edit:**

Here's a JSfiddle i set up real quick
[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/wLegfrh3/4/)

Comment: Are any of the jsfiddles and stack-snippets that you can find here helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931271/how-to-enable-responsive-design-for-fabric-js

Comment: Hey @jqueryHtmlCSS thanks for highlighting this to me. However correct me if im wrong but the solution seems to be resizing the fabric based on the viewport O.o, i'm not sure if I can make the canvas resize to the entire page, spanning even the area not visible in the viewing port

Comment: It's much easier for you and others to benefit from this question and participate in improving it when the code is runnable somewhere with just a click or two.

Comment: Okay! Ill try to set up a jsfiddle, have not done this before haha!

Comment: @jqueryHtmlCSS Hey! I have set up a jsfiddle to illustrate the problem thanks for the feedback !

Answer (score 0):

I realize this was a while ago, but if someone else is looking for an answer - I think it's the css.  Change it from "fixed" to "absolute", and you should be good to go. `position: absolute !important;`